# Machine Epsilon Calculation Error in C++

Tags: c++, math, recursion

I am trying to find the precision and error for the Machine Epsilon. Without using std::numeric_limits. I was given the following formula by my professor y = 1-x/2^n, n > 1. I am assuming that y is the Machine Epsilon, x is 1.0, and n should be the precision.

Here is my header file macEpsFloat.hpp:

```
class MacEpsFloat
{

public:

  int precision(int n);

private:
  float e = 1.0; //error
  float x = 1.0; //variable
  float y = 0.0; //variable
  int prec = 0;
 };
```

Here is my macEpsFloat.cpp file

```
int MacEpsFloat::precision(int n)
{
    y = 1 - (x/(1<<n));

    if (y == 1.0)
    {
        prec = n-1;
    }
    else
    {
        float error = std::abs(e - y);
        std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
        ++n;
        precision(n);
    }
    return prec;
}
```

Here is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "macEpsFloat.hpp"


int main()
{

    MacEpsFloat a;

    std::cout << "Precision Float: " << a.precision(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

The variable y is set equal to 1.0, e is set equal to 1.0, and n is set equal to 1.

I get the following output:

```
error: 0.5
error: 0.25
error: 0.125
error: 0.0625
error: 0.03125
error: 0.015625
error: 0.0078125
error: 0.00390625
error: 0.00195312
error: 0.000976562
error: 0.000488281
error: 0.000244141
error: 0.00012207
error: 6.10352e-05
error: 3.05176e-05
error: 1.52588e-05
error: 7.62939e-06
error: 3.8147e-06
error: 1.90735e-06
error: 9.53674e-07
error: 4.76837e-07
error: 2.38419e-07
error: 1.19209e-07
error: 5.96046e-08
Precision Float: 24
```

On the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) there are 2 answers for Floats. The first is 1.19209e-07 with a precision of 23, and the other is 5.96046e-08 with a precision of 24.

I see both answers right there, so I know I am on the right track. However, I do not understand why my recursive algorithm divides the problem one more time. I believe the answer I am looking for is 5.96046e-08, or 1.19209e-07 if I multiply it by 2. However, I am not sure what is wrong with my code on why it is executing one more time.

The other issue I am having is this piece of code does not work with doubles for any reason. So I would like to know why that is. Is it better to just throw this into a while loop and see if anything changes? Or do I have the formula wrong for Machine Epsilon?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: added compiled code.

**EDIT 2:** I solved my initial problem, the error was still being calculated, I simply threw the piece of code into the else statement and now it calculates floating points just fine. However, when I change all the types to doubles, it seg faults, I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: Apply the usual debugging procedure of adding more prints or stepping through your code. It is also standard here to include a full program than can be cut and pasted into a file and compiled.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I have now made an edit, I have added the header file and main.cpp file. I have stepped through the code with a debugger. The if Statement does exactly what it should do when running this code. However, it does not exactly equal 1 on the 24th iteration. It equals something like 0.9999981 so it goes back into the recursive code and when it is executed 1 more time, it inevitably divides it again and adds 1 to it. Leaving my error as 0 and my iterations as 25.

Comment: Isn't this just a logical error? You set precision to `n` at the moment when `error=0`. But `error=0` also for every `n` larger than that. I think the precision is the last value for `n` for which `error!=0`: `epsilon` is the smallest power of `2` which can be added to `1` such that the result can be distinguished from `1`.

Comment: @Walter okay that makes sense. I realized there was an error within my code, I actually moved error into the else statement and now I get the correct error.

However, n is still an issue. Would it make sense to do prec = n-1?

Comment: The seg fault is because of infinite recursion and stack overflow (no pun.) Floating point math is mostly an approximation so you have to know and work with the limitations. Your calculations use `double` and then truncate to `float` and that's works ok. It's not enough to get a good result for `double` however.

Comment: I take that last part back. The calculations are done in `float` but **may** have more precision behind the scenes. The proper result is something like `std::nextafter(1.f, 2.f) - 1.f` and similar for `double`.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano, can you rephrase that for me a little bit? If I am following you correctly, you are saying that this doesn't work for double because it never hits 1 exactly? If that is the case then why does it work for `float`?

Comment: It really depends on the processor instructions generated by the compiler and how they bits get flipped for those instructions.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano so this piece of code will work differently on another machine?

Comment: Another compiler and/or another processor, yes. I just realized there is a `std::numeric_limits::epsilon()`.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano I am currently using the g++ compiler provided by Ubuntu using the c++14 version. I am thinking that I may have to crack down and use `std::numeric_limits::epsilon()` I was trying to find my own way of solving it without having to use that.

Comment: They are constants supplied by the compiler. There are also the macros `FLT_EPSILON`, `DBL_EPSILON` and `LDBL_EPSILON` in `<float.h>`. Probably `std::numeric_limits` uses the macros but provides a type neutral (template) way of getting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

I changed my function to calculate the error inside of the else statement. That way it would give me the error currently rather than after.

I solved the Seg Fault with the Double variable because I did not realize that (1 << n) could only be shifted 32 times due the the size, or actual architecture of my machine. So after the 32 iteration of the recursion, it would throw out random numbers, eventually dividing by zero causing a Segmentation Fault. The code now looks like this:

```
int MacEpsFloat::precision(int n)
{
    y = 1 - (x/(std::pow(2,n)));

    if (y == 1.0)
    {
        prec = n-1;
    }
    else
    {
        double error = std::abs(e - y);
        std::cout << "Error: " << error << std::endl;
        ++n;
        precision(n);
    }
    return prec;
}
```

I did not realize that I could only bit shift so far. Thank you for everyone who helped out!